# How to wrap this Link with an Image?

Tags: attachments

im working on default wordpress theme twenty eleven, i just wanted to know how can i wrap this previous and next anchor with an image or next/previous button?

```
<span class="nav-previous"><?php previous_image_link( false, __( '&larr; Previous' , 'twentyeleven' ) ); ?></span>
<span class="nav-next"><?php next_image_link( false, __( 'Next &rarr;' , 'twentyeleven' ) ); ?></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing in the image into the functions themselves:

```
<?php 
$previous_image = "<img src='http://domain.com/path/to/image/' alt='Previous Posts'>";
$next_image = "<img src='http://domain.com/path/to/image/' alt='Newer Posts'>";
?>

<span class="nav-previous"><?php previous_image_link( false, $previous_image ); ?></span>
<span class="nav-next"><?php next_image_link( false, $next_image ); ?></span>
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, your suggested answer solved my problem.
Really appreciated your help :)